# AppleScript to Crop Images by Path Selection Without Deleting Pixels in Photoshop

Tags: applescript, crop, photoshop

I need a little help about an AppleScript script which for a folder of pictures :

1. Make a Selection out of already created path named Path 1
2. Then Crops the picture by that selection without Deleting the Cropped pixels

[image: ...]

I have a problem finding the syntax in AppleScript to turn off "Deleting Cropped Pixels"..and looks like there is no such. I am lookin for a solution to save those pixels and a way to implement it in Applescript.

The solution i have uses key code commands and it's pretty inconvenient because "Delete Cropped Pixels" have to turned off manually in Photoshop before runing the script. Any OS notification outside PS will break the script.

```
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set ThePath to choose folder with prompt "Please select folder:"
        set pictures_collection to every file of ThePath
    end tell
    
    repeat with anItem in pictures_collection
        
        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
            activate
            set anItem to anItem as string
            open file anItem
            do action "Make_A_Selection" from "Make_A_Selection" -- runs an action with just makes the selection
            set OpenedPicture to the current document
            tell application "System Events"
-- The option "Delete Cropped Pixels" in the PS Crop tool is turned OFF manually so the next code do not erace the pixels
                key code 8 -- press "C"
                delay 0.5
                key code 36  -- press "enter"
                delay 0.5
                key code 36 -- press "enter"
            end tell
            save OpenedPicture
            close OpenedPicture
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

So i looked for more efficient way but unfortunately i don't know how to implement the option not to "Delete Cropped Pixels" in the next script:

```
on run {input}
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set ThePath to choose folder with prompt "Please select folder:"
        set pictures_collection to every file of ThePath
    end tell
    
    repeat with anItem in pictures_collection
        
        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"'s document 1
            activate
            set anItem to anItem as string
            open file anItem
            create selection path item 1
            tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
                tell current document
                    set theCropBounds to bounds of selection
                    crop bounds theCropBounds
                end tell
            end tell
                save OpenedPicture
                close OpenedPicture
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

I've looked in photoshop-cs6-applescript-reference.pdf but as far as i understood i can only set coordinates of the crop.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are wanting to achieve. However, perhaps you want to replace the complete `tell application "System Events" ... end tell` block in from your first example with the following one line: `do javascript "var idCrop = charIDToTypeID(\"Crop\"); var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor(); executeAction( idCrop, desc2, DialogModes.NO );"` - That would be essentially be the equivalent to manually choosing _"Image"_ > _"Crop"_ from the Menu Bar after "Path_1" has been converted to a selection. See full example [here](https://paste.ee/p/o5mV4)

Comment: @RobC Thank you for responding. I am trying to implement somehow the option "Delete Croped Pixels" in the second script in AppleScript environment and i can't find a syntax for that anywhere. So far i am able to crop folder of pictures using the first script but only if i manually turn off "Delete Croped Pixels" in Photoshop. Unfrortunately i can't count on the the first script because a misclick or a random notification in the OS will break the "key code" comand and the script will stop. It's a solution..but not a practical one.

Comment: I edited the Post so it's more understandable.